# Strange error "ValueError: 'x' cannot be used to seed a numpy.random.RandomState instance" in Support vector Machine?

Tags: python, error-handling, scikit-learn

Bellow, the code throwing a strange error when I am using this piece of code in an application its throwing an error as given below. This Error is because of the "random_state" argument of SVC classifier(https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html).

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import *
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
def Fit_Model(TrainData, Algo):

    print Algo


    df = pd.read_csv(TrainData, sep='\t')
    clm_list = df.columns.tolist()
    X_train = df[clm_list[0:len(clm_list)-1]].values
    y_train = df[clm_list[len(clm_list)-1]].values
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    prob = Algo.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)
    predicted = Algo.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)


def SVM_classification(TrainFile, probability=None, randomRtate=None ):


    pera = {"C":1.0, 
    "kernel":'rbf', 
    "degree":3, 
    "gamma":'scale', 
    "coef0":0.0, 
    "shrinking":True,
    "probability":probability, 
    "tol":0.001, 
    "cache_size":200, 
    "class_weight":None, 
    "verbose":False, 
    "max_iter":-1, 
    "decision_function_shape":'ovr',
    "random_state":randomRtate,

    }

    model = SVC(**pera )


    Fit_Model(TrainData=TrainFile,  Algo=model)



import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-f", "--file_name",
                    required=True,
                    default=None,
                    help="Path to target CSV file")

parser.add_argument("-p", "--proba",
                    required=None,
                    default=False,
                    help="n_folds for Cross Validation")

parser.add_argument("-r", "--Rand",
                    required=None,
                    default=False,
                    help="n_folds for Cross Validation")


args = parser.parse_args()

SVM_classification( args.file_name, args.proba, args.Rand )
```

When I tried to run the script:

```
$ python Stack.py -f Resampled.tsv -p True -r 9
```

Error:

```
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability='True', random_state='9', shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Stack.py", line 68, in <module>
    SVM_classification( args.file_name, args.proba, args.Rand )
  File "Stack.py", line 42, in SVM_classification
    Fit_Model(TrainData=TrainFile,  Algo=model)
  File "Stack.py", line 15, in Fit_Model
    prob = Algo.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)
  File "/home/joshij/anaconda3/envs/Jay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 140, in fit
    rnd = check_random_state(self.random_state)
  File "/home/joshij/anaconda3/envs/Jay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 818, in check_random_state
    ' instance' % seed)
ValueError: '9' cannot be used to seed a numpy.random.RandomState instance
```

However, strange is that I am passing an integer and it's showing the same error, again and again, to test the code I directly pass the "int(8)" but still error is the same.

Example Data "test.tsv":

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    class_label
3   4   5   3   0
2   3   3   4   0
2   3   3   5   0
2   3   3   4   0
2   3   2   4   0
2   3   3   3   1
1   2   3   2   1
1   5   6   9   1
1   2   2   2   1
1   2   2   2   1
```

Please help.

**UPDATE:**

when I changed the

```
"random_state":randomRtate,
```

as

```
"random_state":int(randomRtate),
```

Now different error.

```
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability='True', random_state=9, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Stack.py", line 69, in <module>
    SVM_classification( args.file_name, args.proba, args.Rand )
  File "Stack.py", line 43, in SVM_classification
    Fit_Model(TrainData=TrainFile,  Algo=model)
  File "Stack.py", line 15, in Fit_Model
    prob = Algo.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)
  File "/home/joshij/anaconda3/envs/Jay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 212, in fit
    fit(X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed=seed)
  File "/home/joshij/anaconda3/envs/Jay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 271, in _dense_fit
    max_iter=self.max_iter, random_seed=random_seed)
  File "sklearn/svm/libsvm.pyx", line 64, in sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  You have a lot of undefined variables in what you posted -- most important, it seems that `max_iter` is the problem, rather than `random_state`.

Comment: This chunk belongs to 800+ lines of code, but I will try to do that.

Comment: Post updated in a reproducible manner hope it helps.

Comment: You specified a string seed: `random_state='9'`; this has to be an integer.
Remove the quotation marks.

Comment: I tried this also when I changed the parameters from "random_state":randomRtate to "random_state":int(randomRtate) it shows different errors that you can see in the update section.  and this time it shows 9 as int when you check the variable  type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check *all* of the parameter types.  You've set `class_weight` to `None`, which may overwrite the default case of all `1`.  You've also set `probability` to a string, where a Boolean is required.  If the underlying implementation casts bool to int, you could get the int type error.

Comment: I figure out the problem after posting the questions. Yes, I was passing a default value for the probability as a string "False" rather a boolean False.  But unfortunately, the error message was showing error in random sate parameters rather than the probability.

Answer (score 0):

There are several other parameters that might need to be integers too. Notable examples include `max_iter`, `degree`, and `cache_size`. Try forcing all of those to be integers too.

Comment: I have updated the code in a reproducible way and I added all the parameters manually in this code except these two, and I hope it ruled out your doubt.